# Can somebody help to me:

Tags: missing

my error:

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
 
                   \def 
l.16 \begin{
            document}
?

Comment: Welcome between the users of TeX.SE. What is, please, the full code that gives you this error?

Comment: Remove the space in the command: `\begin{document}`.  This isn't guaranteed to be the problem, but it's an obvious thing to fix.  Spaces in environment names aren't a good idea.